# Elevated Viewpoint to See Dubai Burj Khalifa

Tags: locations

There are a number of amazing photos of the Burj Khalifa which are seemingly taken from an elevated viewpoint. It is possible that some are taken by drone although, I'm not sure drones can get that high at all. What I am looking for a publicly accessible location which would be open until past sunset to take pictures of Dubai with the Burj Khalifa nicely visible.

**Which elevated publicly-accessible locations exist to take photos of the Burj Khalifa?**

Here are some Google Image Search results that have a desirable viewpoint. I would really like to find the viewpoint for the first one as it is most appealing to me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As the second & third shots would appear to cover the point at which the first was taken, then unless something new has been built since, there appears to be no tall structure at all in the vicinity of the first shot's location

Comment: A "drone" has no specific maximum flight level. For example the americans use transformed helicopters as UAV. BTW, a photographer on an helicopter might be an easy explanation. It seems to be the case for image #2

Comment: You might want to try the travel stackexchange site, as you need knowledge of the local area more than you need photographic advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the shots are via helicopter, from a building, or as you mention a drone (the professional quality variants such as the DJI Inspire, Phantom 4 Pro etc). Some keen people attach DSLR via some jiggery pokery.

I believe helicopters utilised for pro or commissioned jobs - eg for the buildings owner

Comment: The quality of what? There are drones that carry DSLRs, gimbaled and stabilized.

Comment: my bad, completely forgot about commerical versions :)

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which buildings in Dubai offer similar vantage points. Otherwise, this really doesn't help me find a viewpoint. I won't have access to a drone and can't afford a helicopter, so I'm really looking for an elevated viewpoint which is accessible to the public, in particular me :)

Comment: @Itai have you considered looking at google maps / google earth as these tools may assist you in possible shot locations

Comment: That's exactly what I spent a few hours doing. The first photo appears to be from the top of the Address Hotel which is closed for renovation. I have not found the other ones.